# Is it necessary to disable the form input in the turkee gem for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanicalturk

I wanted to know if it's necessary to disable the forms and controller for the Turkee Gem. https://github.com/aantix/turkee (see Basic Forms section).

I am trying to debug the error below in development to test in Amazon's sandbox.

**There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT.**

```
This HIT is still assigned to you.  To try this HIT again, click "HITs Assigned To You" in the navigation bar, then click "Continue work on this HIT" for the HIT.  If this problem persists, you can contact the Requester for this HIT using the "Contact" link above.

To return this HIT and continue working on other HITs, click the "Return HIT" button.
```